# Tabulator header filter formatting

Tags: filter, tabulator

Hi I have a tabulator table which the headers are all icons

[image]

I want to add in a fitler box for one field but when I do so using the headerFilter:true the filter is below the icons

[image]

is there any clever way to have the filter on the same level as the icons, space is a premuim on my page so ideally Id like them all aligned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by modifying the tabulator css I had to give the header-filter a negative top position and it now works fine

[image]

```
`.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col .tabulator-header-filter 
{
 position: relative;  
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-top: -23px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 height: 33px ;
} `
```

Comment: would you mind posting the CSS you used to do this so others may benefit from your knowledge?

Comment: Hi Oli of course, I changed the tabulator_bootsrap4.css file and modified the header-filter as below 
`.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col .tabulator-header-filter 
{ position: relative; 
box-sizing: border-box; 
margin-top: -23px; 
width: 100%;
 text-align: center; 
height: 33px ; }`

Comment: You mind editing your answer and posting it in that. It would be easier to read. Cheers :)